# Add <T> to map using specific key and return

Tags: java

Hello stackoverflow community.

I made this code which work fine for List

```
public static <T> T addToList(final T element, final List<T> list)
{
    Objects.requireNonNull(list);

    if (Objects.nonNull(element))
    {
        list.add(element);
    }

    return element;
}
```

which basically add the given element to the list i also provide and return that value.
I want to do the same using MAP<K, V>
but i don't know how i can provide a specific K for the map since the variable i add as parameter is T.

I want to call that method like `addToMap(car, <map_var>, s -> s.getId())`

So i can define in the consumer the KEY

Comment: Which do you want not to be null, the key or the value (or both)? And what do you want to return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want neither key nor value to be non-null, and don't want to return anything from the method:

```
public static <K, V> void addToMap(K key, V value, Map<K, V> map)
{
    Objects.requireNonNull(map);

    if (Objects.nonNull(key) && Objects.nonNull(value))
    {
        map.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

If you want to return, say, `key`, change the return type and add a return statement (you can do similarly for `value`, if that's what you want to return):

```
public static <K, V> K addToMap(K key, V value, Map<K, V> map) {
  // ...
  return key;
}
```

Note that if you want to return `key` but your value is actually a subtype of `map`'s key type, invoking this would return the key cast to the map's key type:

```
Map<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
String keyAsString = addToKey("key", "value", map); // Compiler error.
Object keyAsObject = addToKey("key", "value", map); // OK.
```

If you want to preserve the type of the parameter, use a wildcard:

```
public static <K, V> K addToMap(K key, V value, Map<? super K, V> map) {
  // ...
  return key;
}

String keyAsString = addToKey("key", "value", map); // Now ok.
```

Comment: Thank you i made it on my own way before i read your comment. But thanks anyway. I used callable for key is that ok? final Callable<T> key)

Comment: You need to be careful using something like `Callable` as a key because an implementation of that interface may or may not have stable `hashCode` and `equals` implementations.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like. The key returned will need to be typecasted appropriately.

```java
public static <K, V> K addToMap(final K key, final V value, final Map<K, V> map) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(map);
        if (Objects.nonNull(key) && Objects.nonNull(value)) {
            map.put(key, value);
        }
        return key;
    }
```

Comment: Great answer!! Thanks